# Trouble with Guard init command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, guard

I'm trying to setup `Guard` using [this](http://ygamretuta.me/2011/08/10/rails-3-setting-up-guard-with-rspec-and-spork-with-growl-notifications-in-osx/) tutorial, however when I run `bundle exec guard init` or `bundle exec guard init rspec`

I'm on OSX, running RVM 1.14.1 and Rails 3.2.5.

I get the following errors:

```
[myapplication]$ bundle exec guard init rspec
/Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/gems/guard-1.1.0/lib/guard/cli.rb:145:in `init': undefined method `create_guardfile' for Guard:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/task.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120:in `invoke_task'
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor.rb:275:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/gems/thor-0.15.2/lib/thor/base.rb:408:in `start'
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/gems/guard-1.1.0/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/bin/guard:19:in `load'
    from /Users/ash/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@myapplication/bin/guard:19:in `<main>'
```

`RSpec` runs fine:

```
[myapplication]$ bundle exec rspec
F

Failures:

  1) StaticPages GET /static_pages works! (now write some real specs)
     Failure/Error: get static_pages_index_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `static_pages_index_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fd6d176a020>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.00887 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:5 # StaticPages GET /static_pages works! (now write some real specs)
```

Also my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.5'
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'growl'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork'
end
gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've reported this issue and it has been fixed:

https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/283#issuecomment-6078721

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem in Ubuntu Server 11.10. In my case there was some problem with the versions of the gems. I changed the guard gem version in the Gemfile from 1.1.0 to 0.10.0 and it worked. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'

group :development, :test do
  #gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  gem 'guard','0.10.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '0.5.5'
  gem 'guard-bundler'

end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'rb-inotify', '0.8.8'
  gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: You're right downgrading fixes it. Apparently it's a known issue - https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/283#issuecomment-6078721. You can downgrade to version '1.0.3' to fix this issue.